# Map box API is not working in react?

Tags: reactjs, web, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

> Mapbox

access token is generated. Acces token is set as `mapboxgl.accessToken = 'your access token';`

But it shows a valid API access token is required to access Mapbox data.

[Workout code is here](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl)

Error is here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrB0E.png)

Comment: Get your access token from [here](https://www.mapbox.com/account/)

Comment: I already used that new created acess token.

Comment: Add access token as in this example https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/blob/master/examples/controls/src/app.js

Comment: Yes..now It works well . Thankyou.